# Get SSL Certificate for a request

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

Is there a way of getting **the current SSL Certificate for a request** in a .Net Application (C#) ?

I can see if it is a Secure Connection, but I cannot access the SSL Certificate (X509Certificate2 or similar).

I want to use this certificate to sign a string without having to have another certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [ServicePoint.Certificate Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.certificate(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://foo.com");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();

var cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that will give me the ssl certificate for foo.com, not the site running my code. 

I have an aspx page running on a secure site in which I would like to get the context's ssl certificate.

Comment: @João if you want to use your certificate then you have it in your file system.... and you can easly access it without doing a request

Comment: Ok, thought there could be another way besides querying the certificate store.